# Which tools do I need in order to use ES6 style imports for my project using Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-module-loader

I have a legacy project which uses Gulp to compile SASS and minify JS etc. (based on Drupal).

I'd like to use ES6 style imports and also be able to import modules that are located in `node_modules` without referencing the full path (for example import the lodash.debounce module as

```
  import throttle from 'lodash.throttle'
```

What do I need to achieve that? (besides Gulp and NPM). Babel? Browserify? Lost with all the tooling.

I'd like to avoid webpack as it would increase the complexity of my project (and I don't know if I can use it in parallel with the way Drupal 7 is doing things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you want babel. The documentation to set it up in your gulpfile is here: http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

You'll want to use the es2015 preset to enable the import syntax.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task("default", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/app.js")
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015']
     }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Comment: check edited question: is this enough for me be able to import directly modules located in `node_modules` without referencing the entire path? so :
 `import throttle from 'lodash.throttle'`

Comment: Edited my answer, you're right, you need the es2015 preset too.

Comment: does this mean during production NPM and the node modules should be present in the server?

Comment: Yes. Babel won't pack it all together, it'll just transpile the es2016 code into syntax a browser can understand (es5). That's what webpack is for. If you're serving a webpage you probably don't want to use this in production without packing and minifying with webpack or browserify, or you're going to end up serving a few megabytes worth of JS on every page load. It's really slow with a lot of overhead.

Comment: Therefore you should consider using another module like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify"

Comment: alright, I'll look into browserify or add webpack in the stack. so webpack will pack things for production and the server doesn't need to know anything about what happened before. it's just a concatenated minified file compiled down to ES4 JS..

Answer (score 2):

To use `import` you need a transpiler, for example babel.
Assuming you are building code for the browser then to use `import` (transpiled to `require`) you need webpack or browserify which will also allow you to import from node_modules (there are other module builders too, [jspm](http://jspm.io/) and [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), however I know next-to-nothing about them).
For either of these you will also need something to enable babel to be used in the build process.  I use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) with [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader).

I found a useful reference [here](http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/using-es6-modules-with-webpack/) specifically on using ES6 modules with webpack.

Comment: does this mean during production NPM and the node modules should be present in the server?

Comment: no, webpack will bundle in the modules you need.  This can end up with a very large chunk of js so minification (uglify or similar) is recommended.  Webpack (and browserify) can then also produce map files so that debugging is easier.

Comment: thank you. I implemented a browserify solution for now, but I think webpack might be a better choice.